# Html: Is it possible to have infinite (finite?) scrolling with a static html using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, static

I have static html files automatically generated and saved in S3. Sometimes a file reaches 2mb size. Is it possible to use javascript to fetch a part of an html file, display it and when user reaches bottom of page, fetches next part and so on?

Comment: yes it is, look at Twitter! Although you will need an endpoint on your server to provide the data to load

Comment: @Alex, your best bet would be to store the large file in smaller files and then have JS fetch each as your scroll down.

Comment: @cowls: Thanks. Yes I know it's possible to use a server for infinite scrolling but I'm using static files only.

Comment: Another good example of this is WordPress. Once you have 10 blog posts or so, the next post you create goes onto a new "page." When you scroll to the bottom of the page, it fetches the next 10 posts. Similar to @sachleen's suggestion.

Comment: You could potentially create static json files that only represent parts of documents, then load them in through an AJAX call

Comment: Actually, Ajax can load the content of html files. Use sachleen solution by splitting your html in smaller files and load it with ajax.

Comment: For any solution to this, you'll have to be careful (which you may have already handled) that you don't wind up loading an element half way through that has some cool inline style or CSS class that means that it actually appears at the top - otherwise results could be disappointing/hilarious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally possible - the idea is that you can pre-render "fragments" on the server, where each fragment represents a "subpage" of N articles or what have you. You then render the page with 0 (or 1) fragments, and send it to the client. When the client scrolls to the bottom, you simply request the next fragment (with AJAX) and append it to the end of the previous fragment. Keep doing this indefinitely.

The key point to understand is that each fragment is rendered statically on the server. Though the fragment may not be a complete HTML page in and of itself, they are "infinitely appendable" into an existing page. Part of the fun of HTTP (as opposed to full HTML) is that you don't have to have a full HTML page for any fragment to be successfully served; you can think of the HTML as "boilerplate" that surrounds arbitrary chunks of additional, non-well-formed HTML (that become well-formed when placed inside your boilerplate).

Since AJAX is based around HTTP requests, you can ask for any arbitrary content. Heck, you can ask for your own custom markup as long as the Javascript that "catches" the response can format it in a way the browser can understand - namely, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

The [XHR Object](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader%28%29-method) provides a method for setting up custom HTTP headers. So, you could try setting up the [Range header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) in order to fetch just a part of the static file.

You will have to account for the chunk not being proper HTML, since you're cutting an arbitrary slice of the file, so you will have to implement logic to properly handle the results if you intend to display them.

I'd love to see you implement it this way, instead of leveraging the chunking to the server as is the usual case.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not how can I do infinite scrolling, it's really how can I load parts of a large file at a time, loading more as the user scrolls down. I'm not sure if that's possible so here's another solution:

Store the large file in smaller chunks, lets say `1.txt, 2.txt ...` Then, on your page, as you scroll down, you can load the next `N.txt`. (doesn't have to be txt, by the way). Just make sure your wrapper (the file that the user actually sees) has complete HTML and the chunks that it's loading is just the content. Meaning the chunks shouldn't have like a `</body></html>`... that should be in the wrapper file.

Here's [how to fetch a file using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437447/ajax-reading-from-file) or using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). All you really have to do is keep track of what part you're on so you can load the next one. If it doesn't exist, then you've loaded the entire file.