# Jquery get url for "href", from an external file

Tags: jquery, load, href, external, attr

I want to load an url from an external file, for an attribute "href". My code :

```
var url = $("file.php div#data").html()

$("a#myLink").attr('href',url);
```

This doesn't work. Why ? Should I use ".load" ? ".ajax" ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use AJAX to load the file. However, it might be easier to use PHP to output the JS for the link, seeing as JavaScript without AJAX can't access files (due to the JS engine's security settings).

`var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile.open("GET", "http://my.remote.url/myremotefile.txt", true);
txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (txtFile.readyState === 4) {  // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
    if (txtFile.status === 200) {  // Makes sure it's found the file.
      allText = txtFile.responseText; 
      lines = txtFile.responseText.split("\n"); // Will separate each line into an array
    }
  }
}
txtFile.send(null);`

Answer reproduced from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5437603/2225787

Comment: If it works for you, please mark this aor iCore's answer as accepted by clicking on the tick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with several AJAX functions, like:

```
$.ajax('file.php').done(function(e) {
    $('a#myLink').attr('href', e);
});
```